# Unable to change display language in Twitter app on S4

Tags: applications, settings, samsung-galaxy-s-4, languages, twitter

I want to change the laguage Twitter is displayed in from English to German. I can easily do this from the laptop web version. However the Language is still in english on my app.

Some notifacations bubbles that pop up on my phone are auf Deutsch.

Is the display language for the App always default to your location?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The Twitter app language match the current phone's language. With a English US phone, my app is set to en-Us.